# c# SSIS Script Task Error The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I'm using SQL Server 2017 \ SSIS \ Visual Studio 2019.  I am trying to build a web scraping task that will pass the values to a SQL table, via a c# Script Component transformation.

The script consists of two parts:

main.cs:

```cs
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    try
    {
        WebScrape WBScrape = new WebScrape();
        Row.DescriptionText = WBScrape.read_text_page(Row.Links);
    }
    catch (Exception UnknownError1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(UnknownError1.Message);

    }

}
```

And WebScrape.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace SC_68c409392de64cb2b3012e25a1dc514c
{
    class WebScrape
    {
        const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = @"(<(!--|script) (.|\n[^<]) * (--|script)>)|(<|&lt;) (/?[\w!?]+)\s?[^<]*(>|&gt;)|(\&[\w]+\;)";


        private string StripHTML(string inputString) => Regex.Replace(inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);

        public string read_text_page (string pagelink)
        {
            string tempstring = string.Empty;
            int count = 0;
            string hold_temp_values = string.Empty;

            // used to build entire input
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //used on each read operation
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            //prepare the web page we will be asking for
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pagelink);

            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36";

            // execute the request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // we will read data via the response stream
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            do
            {
                // fill the buffer with data
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                WebScrape tempString = null;

                // make sure we read some data
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    //transalate from bytes to ASCII text
                    tempstring = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                    // continue building the string
                    sb.Append(tempString);

                }

            }
            while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

            hold_temp_values = StripHTML(sb.ToString()).Trim();

            if (hold_temp_values.Length > 8000)
            {
                hold_temp_values = hold_temp_values.Substring(0, 8000);

            }

            else
            {
            }

            return hold_temp_values;
        }

    }

    internal class HttpWebRequest
    {
        public string UserAgent { get; internal set; }

        internal HttpWebResponse GetResponse()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static explicit operator HttpWebRequest(WebRequest v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the SSIS package I receive a message box stating:

> The method or operation is not implemented

This is obviously firing from the main.cs - but what does it actually mean - where do I need to look?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the point of your `internal class HttpWebRequest`? That's where this Exception is from: It doesn't have a `Create()` method and its `GetResponse()` throws the `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: How do I actually do that though?

Comment: Firstly, take this out of SSIS and just create a standalone C# console app.

Comment: Delete that whole `internal class HttpWebRequest`, and use System.Net.HttpWebRequest instead.

Comment: I agree with Filburt, why you are using the internal HttpWebRequest class?

Comment: ah ok, sorry I inherited this from someone else.  Do I literally just replace internal class HttpWebRequest with System.Net.HttpWebRequest?

Comment: If I remove the line:

        internal HttpWebResponse GetResponse()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

It now complains on this line:

            // execute the request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

saying it doesn't contain a definition for GetResponse

I'm lost